# .NET QuickFix wrong Logout message sent at logon

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix

I'm using .NET wrapper for QuickFix with the latest binaries from QuickFix site (1.13.3).

The session is configured as acceptor and scheduled daily from **06:10:00** to **15:35:00**.

The problem is that when the other party attempts first logon in  the morning our engine sends an unwanted `Logout` message and does not reset sequence numbers from the last day.

I've added custom logging of the `Session` properties in the `toApp` method and this gets logged when the other party sends first `Logon` message (toApp time is UTC+1):

```
20121128-06:46:14.546 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=63|35=A|49=OTHER_PARTY|56=US|34=1|52=20121128-06:46:14|98=0|108=60|141=Y|10=046

2012-11-28 07:46:14,546 [3] DEBUG FixAcceptor.FIX.4.2-US-OTHER_PARTY [(null)] <(null)> - Session 'FIX.4.2:US->OTHER_PARTY',   isLoggedOn: False,   isSessionTime: True,   sentLogon: False,   sentLogout: False,   receivedLogon: False  

20121128-06:46:14.546 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=50|35=5|34=79|49=US|52=20121128-06:46:14.546|56=OTHER_PARTY|10=225|
```

I don't understant why is this `Logout` message being sent. The session of the previous day ended with normal logout from both parties. When the other party sends another `Logon` message everything goes well and normal `Logon` response is sent:

```
20121128-06:46:24.765 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=63|35=A|49=OTHER_PARTY|56=US|34=2|52=20121128-06:46:24|98=0|108=60|141=Y|10=048  
20121128-06:46:24.780 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=67|35=A|34=1|49=US|52=20121128-06:46:24.780|56=OTHER_PARTY|98=0|108=60|141=Y|10=000
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

**EDIT**
I've checked the logs again today and the yesterday's logout procedure was done properly but the sequence numbers didn't get reset and the Logout message was again sent today morning:

```
20121128-15:07:22.248 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=54|35=5|49=OTHER_PARTY|56=US|34=262|52=20121128-15:07:22|58=END|10=192|  
20121128-15:07:22.248 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=51|35=5|34=262|49=US|52=20121128-15:07:22.248|56=OTHER_PARTY|10=007|  
20121129-06:23:25.326 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=63|35=A|49=OTHER_PARTY|56=US|34=1|52=20121129-06:23:25|98=0|108=60|141=Y|10=044|  
20121129-06:23:25.341 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=51|35=5|34=263|49=US|52=20121129-06:23:25.341|56=OTHER_PARTY|10=004|  
20121129-06:23:35.544 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=63|35=A|49=OTHER_PARTY|56=US|34=2|52=20121129-06:23:35|98=0|108=60|141=Y|10=046|  
20121129-06:23:35.560 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=67|35=A|34=1|49=US|52=20121129-06:23:35.560|56=OTHER_PARTY|98=0|108=60|141=Y|10=250|
```

So if the wrong sequence number is the reason for Logout message being sent, the question remains why is QuickFix not reseting the sequence numbers. I've checked and StartDay/EndDay config params are not being set during session configuration, only StartTime/EndTime. Anything other I should check?

Comment: Why do you not use the .net quickfix implementation? No wrapper needed.

Comment: @TomTom The project started before the .net implementation was available and until now we didn't have motive to switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Logon 34=1

Logout 34=79
```

The sequence number expected is 78 probably. Either you have to reset your sequence number or need to ask the initiator to use the sequence number it last used to send a message to your acceptor.

The following tags in the config file should help you out. All of them are N by default, you may have to change the required tag to Y to allow sequence numbers to be reset at logon/logout/disconnect.

```
ResetOnLogon    
ResetOnLogout   
ResetOnDisconnect
RefreshOnLogon
```

My assumption is that session logout doesn't happen properly because of which Quickfix still retains the old sequence number. And on the 1st logout resets the sequence number. Maybe ResetOnLogout is set.

Comment: I've checked the logs again today. Yesterday's logout was done properly:

Comment: @bartol82 Which reset flags have you or your counterparty has set in your(others) config file ??

Comment: None of these settings (ResetOnLogon, ResetOnLogout, ResetOnDisconnect, RefreshOnLogon) is explicitly set on our side so they should have the default value ('N').
I don't know which engine is the other party using or it's session settings. How could they affect our QuickFix behavior in this case?

Comment: @bartol82 - Whatever setting the other side could be a blackbox to you. Don't you have a user level agreement with the user ? Best case scenario is set the ResetOnLogon as Y in your config. But the main concern is, the other side should know that seq no will be reset when they log on. But I presume they assume so, when they try to login with 1 when they login.

Comment: You're right, we did agree that the sequence numbers will be reset once daily while they are offline. I don't see they sending anything wrong. It is our engine that is not behaving correctly, i.e. as expected. We're trying to figure out why is our QuickFix sending that unnecessary Logout message when they try to logon for the first time in the morning.

Comment: @bartol82 - Why don't you set ResetOnLogon as Y ? If you have no settings and they send a login message your sequence numbers would not be in sync. I believe your engine is persisting the seq nos. So you set either of the config flags to reset your seq nos once when they login.